# VMware no longer compiles after upgrade

Tags: 10.10, vmware, compiling

I used VMware on ubuntu 10.04 for quite a while. When 10.10 was released I did a clean install. I tried to reinstall VMware, but after installing, I wasn't able to compile the modules. Does anybody know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also had problems running VMWare Player after upgrading Ubuntu from 10.4 to 10.10 as it could not recompile it's modules (due to the changes in kernel) - [this guide](http://www.rrfx.net/2010/06/vmware-vmmon-module-compilation-issues.html) helped to solve that issue.

Also I've had issues with non-compilable VMCI Sock module (due to the changes in the kernel). Please see [this link](http://www.debuntu.org/how-wmware-workstation-7.1-ubuntu-maverick-meerkat-10.10) for the solution.

These two patches worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to compile. And afterwards the guide told me how to fix VMware compiling every time you run it. No more problems now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Welcome and thanks to the guys who has created those guides. :)

Answer (score 2):

As of now, according the VMware forums, you must upgrade VMware to version 7 to use VMware Workstation under Ubuntu 10.10. A updated version of VMware 6, compatible with Ubuntu 10.10, maybe released at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until VMWare launches an update making it compilable on newer Linux kernels. The modules may not build because of inconsistencies between VMWare's modules and the internal Linux Kernel API.